# Outlook 2007 unable to connect to exchange server

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, connection, exchange

I came into the office a week ago and outlook has refused to connect ever since, it just says "Disconnected" in the bottom right-hand corner. I've tried restarting it, rebooting Windows etc.

I'm the only one if our office who is having this problem, so it's not a general problem with the server.

Things I've tried

1. Pinging the server via IP address and host name, both work fine
2. Connecting via OWA, this works using the same machine name
3. Connecting to Exchange via HTTP ("Outlook Anywhere") doesn't work
4. None of the suggestions in this question helped, https://serverfault.com/questions/21755/can-ping-exchange-server-cant-connect-outlook-to-it
5. Disabling Windows firewall on my laptop also has no effect.

There are no items in the event viewer that indicate that anything it up. Also no permissions have changed on the server since when it worked.

**Update:** I've just tried logging onto a completely different PC, using my domain controller user-name/password. When I setup outlook on there it also fails, so the problem isn't specific to 1 pc/outlook it's something about my particular user name, but not when using OWA?

What else can I do to diagnose this, any suggestions?

Comment: When you tried the new setup on the different PC, and 'it failed' what was the reason/error that OL gave in regards to the failure? When did it fail (ie: did the initial profile setup finish)?

Comment: Try ctrl-right-clicking on the Outlook icon in the Taskbar and select "Connection status...". This will give you an idea of which servers and which methods Outlook is trying to connect to.

Comment: Look into this link. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/use-outlook-anywhere-to-connect-to-your-exchange-server-without-vpn-HP010102444.aspx This was helpful with the Windows 7 not connecting to MS Exchange (email server).

Answer (score 1):

Check to make sure that Outlook is pointed to the right server.  I had a user report a similar problem after we migrated to a new Exchange box.

Start-> right click Outlook-> Properties

Click Email Accounts

Account Settings dialogue box appears.

Highlight the account (it's usually Microsoft Exchange)

Click Change (3rd option right below tabs)

Verify that the server is the correct server.

Comment: No tried that, it already has the right name. Also if I clear out the 2 boxes (server and username), enter them again and click "Check Names" it finds them okay.

Answer (score 1):

Have you or the Exchange admin checked the logs on the Exchange server for errors or other messages that might point you in a new direction?  Anything in the event log on your system or the other one you tried? Always a good place to start?

Comment: I am the exchange admin (we're a small company). I've looked in the event logs of both the server and my machine and neither have any events that that seem related?? There's no events related to outlook that mentioned why I can't connect.

Comment: Can you telnet to the exchange server and connect using your credentials?

Answer (score 1):

call the domain sysadmin make sure u'r account or hostname is not on the restrict login

Answer (score 1):

You even diagnose using online tool provided by microsoft.

https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com

I had solved my problem that way.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to the network connection, check if the DNS IP address is the one with the Exchange server. If not, configure it with TCP/IP to use the DNS that has the Exchange server.

Answer (score 0):

I have a few users that are having this problem of connecting to the Exchange server recently. I cannot find the cause but to get them connect, I disable the LAN connection and then enable it as all of them are manually configured. After that, I click on the send/receive icon and Outlook gets connected.

It works for me but not sure it will work for you. I am still not sure if this is an Exchange problem or my local LAN.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem recently. 
I was able to connect over http(OWA) but not through Office Outlook.I came to realize few days later that I changed DNS settings and that was main reason for me.Everything came back to normal after restoring DNS settings.